# Visual Studio 2010 is rebuilding whole project on Ctrl + Shift + B instead of compiling only changed files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am facing an odd issue. Upon pressing control + shift + B in vs 2010, compilation of all files starts over rather than compiling only the modified file. I do not remember changing anything in the settings category. Help me to get over this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PDF Document](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&srcfamilyid=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f&srcdisplaylang=en&u=http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/6/296AAFA4-669A-46FE-9509-93753F7B0F46/VS-KB-Brochure-CSharp-Letter.pdf) here from Microsoft CTRL-SHIFT-B is supposed to rebuild all projects in the solution. Shift-F6 does just the modified project you are in. If you are working in another language you may find the [shortcut lists here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189).

Comment: Hey specifically speaking, I am working on vs 2010 (vc++). I have been using that shortcut since time immemorial and upon doing that the compiler has compiled only the updated or modified file. So I do not think that's an issue.